# Better way to do this LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ to query the DbContext to get the IDs of people staying in a specific room. After that I use LINQ again to fetch `Person` from the `People` table using `foreach person` where their ID matches and add them to my list of `Person` because my viewmodel needs it. I'm sure there is a better way to write this any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{          
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Room room = db.Rooms.Find(id);
    if (room == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    List<Person> pList = new List<Person>();
    var query = (from c in db.RoomsPeople
                 where c.RoomID == room.ID
                 select c).ToList();

    foreach(RoomPerson r in query)
    {
        var asdf =(from c in db.People
                   where c.ID == r.PersonID
                   select c).ToList();

        pList.Add(asdf[0]);
    }
    NewMvc.ViewModels.RoomPerson rp = new NewMvc.ViewModels.RoomPerson();
    rp.Room = room;
    rp.People = pList;
    return View(rp);
}
```

Comment: you should consider inner join between People and  RoomsPeople

Comment: On a more general note, calling `ToList()` where the only thing you do with that list is access `[0]` could be replaced with just calling `First()`. Don't call `ToList()` unless you actually need a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an inner join between the two tables:

```
var peopleInRoom = (from roomsPeople in db.RoomsPeople
                    join people in db.People on roomsPeople.PersonID equals people.ID
                    where roomsPeople.RoomID == room.ID
                    select people).ToList();
```

Comment: Getting error rp is being used before it is declared?

Comment: nevermind seemed to be finding the rp instance i created at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption that you have a navigation property between `RoomsPeople` and `People`. If that exists I'd rewrite it using the fluent syntax and not mess with LINQ's weird join syntax.

```
var list = db.RoomsPeople
    .Include(rp => rp.People)
    .Where(rp => rp.RoomID == room.ID)
    .Select(rp => new NewMvc.ViewModels.RoomPerson()
        {
            Room = rp,
            People = rp.People
        }
    .ToList();
```

You may not even need the `.Include` call, I'd have to try it to be sure.